# Perl FFMpeg print output

Tags: perl, ffmpeg, system

Hi im using the following perl command to convert files with ffmpeg:

```
system ("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i $inputFile $outputFile");
```

I would like to know if its possible to print the ffmpeg output?

Cheers

**UPDATE**

The solution was to use backticks

```
my $output = qx{/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i $inputFile $outputFile 2>&1};
print $output
```

This prints out the following:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r26402, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers built on Jan 31 2012 12:30:35 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6) configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --disable-mmx --enable-shared libavutil 50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0 libavcore 0.16. 1 / 0.16. 1 libavcodec 52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0 libavformat 52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0 libavdevice 52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3 libavfilter 1.74. 0 / 1.74. 0 libswscale 0.12. 0 / 0.12. 0 [wav @ 0x8af94c0] max_analyze_duration reached Input #0, wav, from 'a.wav': Duration: 00:00:05.84, bitrate: 1537 kb/s Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s Output #0, mp3, to 'a.mp3': Metadata: TSSE : Lavf52.93.0 Stream #0.0: Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s Stream mapping: Stream #0.0 -> #0.0 Press [q] to stop encoding size= 42kB time=5.42 bitrate= 64.0kbits/s size= 46kB time=5.88 bitrate= 64.0kbits/s video:0kB audio:46kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.070153%
```

Comment: Instead of editing your question give the solution you found, post it as an answer (yes, its perfectly OK to answer your own question—and even to select your answer as the best one)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: FFmpeg throws its output to the StandrdError instead of StandrdOutput